# Why is this compiler error happening?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-errors, private, mingw32

I am working on exception handling for a piece of software I write in C++. I encounter a compiler error (using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 / mingw32) I don't understand, here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class Bad_Img_Load: public std::exception {
    //public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw(){
        return "An image could not be loaded.";
    }
};

int main () {
    try{
        throw Bad_Img_Load();
    }catch (Bad_Img_Load& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:6:22: error: 'virtual const char* Bad_Img_Load::what() const' is private
  virtual const char* what() const throw(){
                      ^
a.cpp:15:25: error: within this context
     std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
                         ^
```

Note that if I uncomment the line 'public:' then it works just fine. But the class 'exception' from which it inherits defines everything as public. So I don't understand why this error crops up at all.

Comment: Why do you expect the overridden function to be public if you declare it private?

Comment: @Kenji: No they don't do it. I don't see it at the link. At your link they always catch the exception as `std::exception &e`, which is why they have access to *public* `e.what()`. They never catch their exceptions as user-defined type. You catch your exceptions as `Bad_Img_Load& e`, which is a completely different story.

Comment: You're right, AnT, I just noticed. Now I get it. I have no clue why that confused me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if whether the class you're inheriting from has all it's members public. If you overload an inherited class' public function with a (in your code implicitly specified) private access-specifier, then the overload is private. Technically, you could say that you're overloading the access-specifier too.

Answer (score 1):

There's basically one thing that makes `struct` and `class` different, and that's the default visibility. For `struct` the default is `public` and for `class` the default is `private`.

Whoever told you that `class` have default `public` visibility is wrong. Any beginners textbook will tell you the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made a mistake. I wanted to write it should inherit the public from its superclass.